# COUNT(*) of a windowed SQL range

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres 9.1 I'm using a windowing function like so:

```sql
SELECT a.category_id, (dense_rank() over w) - 1
FROM (
    _inner select_
) a
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY score)
```

What I can't figure out is how to also select the total number of elements in the windowed range.  If I just use `count(*) over w` that tells me how many elements I've seen in the window *so far* instead of the total number in the window.

My core issue here is that cume_dist() counts from 1, not 0, for the number of rows before or equal to you.  percentile_rank() counts from 0, like I need, but then it also subtracts 1 from the total number of rows when it does it's division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.category_id,
    (dense_rank() over w) - 1,
    count(*) over (partition by category_id) --without order by
FROM (
    _inner select_
) a
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY score)
```

[From the manual on Window Functions:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

> There is another important concept associated with window functions: for each row, there is a set of rows within its partition called its window frame. Many (but not all) window functions act only on the rows of the window frame, rather than of the whole partition. By default, if ORDER BY is supplied then the frame consists of all rows from the start of the partition up through the current row, plus any following rows that are equal to the current row according to the ORDER BY clause. **When ORDER BY is omitted the default frame consists of all rows in the partition**

Comment: I'd like to give +1 here but this is so amazingly cool that I can't get it through my think skull to see if works...  Obrigado for teaching me something new again.